# How can I store user input in Strings?

Tags: java

How can I store each answer from a user's keyboard input in Strings?

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    System.out.println("insert  the answer ");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    String userAnswer[] = new String[3];

    try {
        userAnswer[i] = br.readLine();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println("IO error ,trying to read your answer");
        System.exit(1);
    }
    int count =0;
    count++;
    String we[] = new String[3];

    System.out.println("the answer is  " + userAnswer);
    System.out.println("the answer is  " + count);
}
```

Comment: what is wrong with this code?

Comment: Are you trying to take in a single input and split it into three strings? Are you trying to input three separate strings? Your intentions aren't clear.

Answer (score 3):

Use [Scanner](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html).

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
List<String> answers = new ArrayList<String>();
for( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
{
   answers.add(scanner.nextLine());
}
```

Comment: After that, you'll use a foreach to print your answers.